# How to append a copy of an existing LinearLayout underneath it when a button is clicked?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to make a program where at some point the user will have to add some school subjects as input. I created the input field (see image below), where when clicking the "Add" button, an equal field will be created underneath it. The "Remove" button serves to remove an input field, but there must be at least one input field.

[image: Later]

As I'm new to Android development, I'd like to know how to do this. I already researched some websites but I was only able to generate individual elements, such as TextViews, using `addView`:

```
val relLay = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.relLay1)
val btnAdd = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnAdd)
btnAdd.setOnClickListener{
    val tv = TextView(this)
    tv.text = "This is a text view"
    val params : RelativeLayout.LayoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    params.setMargins(10, pos, 10, 10)
    pos += 50     // pos is a variable that was declared previously
    rellay.addView(tv)
}
```

How do I generate these elements in a group? And besides, after creating other fields like this, when the user clicks "Done", how do I read the data of all the fields created?

My `input_activity.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/relLay1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relLay2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            ...

            <!-- Title of the input field -->
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Add subject"
                    android:layout_below="@id/table1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textSize="36sp"
                    android:id="@+id/txtSubtitle2"/>

            <!-- LinearLayout that I want to be created
            every time the user clickes the button Add -->
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/linLay1"
                    android:layout_below="@id/txtSubtitle2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/edtSubjectNam"
                        android:hint="Subject name"/>
                <TextView
                        android:text="Days of the week"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:id="@+id/string3"/>
                <CheckBox
                        android:text="Sunday"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                        android:id="@+id/checkSun"/>
                <CheckBox
                        android:text="Monday"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                        android:id="@+id/checkMon"/>
                <CheckBox
                        android:text="Tuesday"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                        android:id="@+id/checkTue"/>
                <CheckBox
                        android:text="Wednesday"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                        android:id="@+id/checkWed"/>
                <CheckBox
                        android:text="Thursday"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                        android:id="@+id/checkThu"/>
                <CheckBox
                        android:text="Friday"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                        android:id="@+id/checkFri"/>
                <CheckBox
                        android:text="Saturday"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                        android:id="@+id/checkSat"/>

                <!-- LinearLayout of the buttons Done, Remove and Add -->
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <Button
                            android:text="Done"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                            android:id="@+id/btnDone"
                            android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <Button
                            android:text="Add"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                            android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <Button
                            android:text="Remove"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:id="@+id/btnRem"
                            android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My code in Kotlin (`InputActivity.kt`) is still empty because I could not do very much. Any help is very, very welcome. I would also like some help from what the "Remove" button code would look like, but my biggest concern is about the "Add" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you'd want to do is make your own layout file with just that view. 
Then you'd inflate the view and add it to your parent view

```
 public View appendView(Activity activity) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.NAME_OF_YOUR_LAYOUT_FILE, null);
    LinearLayout parentLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_CONTAINER);
    parentLayout.addView(view);
}
```

Remove would just be the same but instead of addView you'd do remove view. Might want to add an animation for a fade out though or set the view to animateLayout

To read the data just do view.findViewById(R.id.FIELD) then get the related value from it and save it. Might want to make a class for it